# Probability of a qubit state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

Everything I've read says that you can get the probability of a qubit state by squaring the state's component in the amplitude vector.

For instance $[1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}]$ and $[1/\sqrt{2}, -1/\sqrt{2}]$ both have a 50% chance of being true because squaring $1\sqrt{2}$ and $-1\sqrt{2}$ both result in 0.5.

Squaring doesn't seem to be enough though, due to this vector: $[0,i]$

That ought to come out to be 100% probability of being true, but when you square $i$ you get -1, so it comes out to -100% probability of being true.

It seems like you might need to absolute value the result of the square, but I haven't seen anyone see that before.

Is that the correct way to get probability from amplitude?

**Edit:**

It also seems like there is another wrinkle! In the amplitude vector
$[1/\sqrt{2}, -0.5 -0.5i]$, when i square the $|1\rangle$ state, i get $0.5i$ which definitely needs some more work before being a probability.

Is the right answer that instead of squaring, you need to multiply by the complex conjugate?

Comment: The "square" is the square of the modulus, which you get by multiplying by the conjugate.

Comment: Look at the book of Nielsen and Chuang, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information, they do said probability of observing $0$ and $1$ in $a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle$ is $|a|^2$ and $|b|^2$ not $a^2$ and $b^2$. So in opposite I never saw anyone use the coefficients without absolute value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have rediscovered the fact that $f(x,y)=xy$ is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}$ but not an inner product on $\mathbb{C}$. The usual inner product on $\mathbb{C}$ is $f(x,y)=x\overline{y}$, and $f(x,x)=|x|^2$.

Comment: I wonder if a qubit is the fundamental quantum information : is it not a simple phase $\psi=e^{i\theta}$ ? Which in turn can be immersed in $\psi\hat{=}\pmatrix{a & -b\\b&a}\in M(\mathbb{R})_{2\times 2}$. Hence the measurement of psi is given by diagonalizing a (2x2)x(2x2)=4x4 matrix, and thus can have 4 values ?